# textAngular links from modal dialog sets variable but doesn't apply it to DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, textangular

Using the [textAngular plugin](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular), I'm unable to apply to the DOM a newly set variable. I'm implementing a angular bootstrap UI modal, and I can see the variable is set correctly so the issue appears to be with `editorScope.updateTaBindtaTextElement()`.

Here is my code in the `onElementSelect` block:

```
reLinkButton.on('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl : '/templates/dialog/linkMaker.html',
      controller  : 'linkMakerDlgCtrl',
      resolve     : {
         // variables here ...
         }
      }
   });
   modalInstance.result.then(function (link) {

     $element.attr('href', 'http://' + link.ref); // <== a console.log of this returns the correct value
     editorScope.updateTaBindtaTextElement(); // <== new value not applied to DOM

   }, function () { $log.debug('Modal dismissed'); });

   editorScope.hidePopover();
});
```

As a note, this follows a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099803/use-angular-bootstrap-modal-for-insert-link-in-textangular-editor) with a similar issue on the `action` block and where the solution was to add a `promise` and `return false`. I tried that but it didn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating textAngular version from 1.2.2 to 1.4.3.